# Can GIS software be used to open .ulf files?

Tags: software-recommendations, file-formats

I was sent a .ulf file and I have been trying to open it using various software.

I read at http://fileinfo.com/extension/ulf that this file can be open using gis software.

> Data file formatted in Universal List Format (ULF); contains a list of
>   elements similar to an .XML document; often used by Geographic
>   Information Systems (GIS) applications to store coordinates and
>   vertexes.

Can anyone confirm this and if so, how do I open the file using this software?

Comment: Have you tried opening it in any GIS software. You can quickly install qgis if you dont have one, open and lets know the error you have.

Comment: What is supposed to be contained in the file you were sent?  Some more info would be useful.  Is it supposed to be GIS data?  The file type is used for applications other than GIS.  It could be a Uniware Layout File.  Uniware is accounting software.  If you are in contact with the data provider, ask for a format you're familiar with.

Comment: Since it is claimed to be a XML format, it would be possible to look into it with any text editor and to extract the data using XML based tools.

Answer (score 2):

The same page you reference says it can be opened by [Geosystems MRF Mapping Tool Kit](http://www.mrf.com/) so the the answer to your title question must be **yes**.

Whether or not the file can be opened by many GIS systems I don't know, I've never come across the format before.  I see it isn't listed in the file formats supported by GDAL, either:

- [OGR Vector Formats](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html)
- [GDAL Raster Formats](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html)

So despite its *Universal* name, I think that it's likely to be a proprietary format for the MRF suite of products.